# What is the difference between interface and class?

Tags: class, interface, c++-cli

In C++ I can make `interface` and `class` declarations. However, in contrast to C# the `interface` here is very likely to be a class so why is it there ?

```
interface Interface {

};
```

And

```
class Class {

};
```

Comment: That's not C++. C++/CLI?

Comment: no it is c++ in visual studio!. and it successfully compiles too. @Wintermute

Comment: This is managed C++ not pure C++  In pure C++ there is no "interface" structure.

Comment: It is not a [C++ standard keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), it is a [Visual Studio extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/737cydt1.aspx)

Comment: it's a normal c++ console app, not cli

Comment: @Cyber so how could i tell that a keyword is not c++

Comment: @DanielEugen You ask us, and we tell you it's not standard C++ :)

Comment: @Cyber seems legit :)

Comment: @DanielEugen Here you go  https://isocpp.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in comments, standard C++ does not support an "interface" construct directly.   This is an extension from some vendors.

Other languages do (e.g Java).

The equivalent in standard C++ is an abstract base class, which does not have data members.

```
class SomeInterface
{
    public:
        virtual ~SomeInterface() = 0;
        virtual void SomeAction(int flag) = 0;
};
```

Inheriting from such a class forces the derived class to override/implement all virtual functions, otherwise they cannot be instantiated.

Generally speaking, an abstract base class without data members can often get away without having non-trivial constructors (since the class has no members to initialise).

Unlike other languages that do support an interface construct, the abstract base class permits;

- Having data members in the base class.   (In which case constructors, destructors, assignment operators, etc may need to be defined to manage those members)
- Having some members pure virtual and some not
- Providing implementations of pure virtual methods (which must be explicitly overridden by derived class, but the base class version can be called)